# NoReverseMatch error during url

Tags: python, django

New to Django framework. Mostly reading through documentations.
But this one i am unable to crack.

Trying to add a URL to an headline, that will be forwarded to the 'headlines' post.

The Error:

> NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'assignment_detail' with arguments
>   '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['assignment_detail/'] Request
>   Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version:  2.0.2
>   Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for
>   'assignment_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['assignment_detail/'] Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py
>   in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version:   3.6.2 Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\codepython', 
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\Scripts\python36.zip',
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib', 
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\Scripts', 
>   'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\Lib',  'c:\program files
>   (x86)\python36-32\DLLs', 
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env', 
>   'C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:  Thu, 8 Feb 2018 14:53:07 +0000 Error during template
>   rendering In template
>   C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\codepython\codepython\templates\base.html,
>   error at line 0
>
> Reverse for 'assignment_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['assignment_detail/'] 1    {% load static %}
>   2  3    4   5     6       7         8       9       10        CODEPYTHON.NET
>   Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
>   C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py
>   in inner
>               response = get_response(request) ... ▶ Local vars C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py
>   in _get_response
>                   response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ... ▶ Local vars
>   C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py
>   in _get_response
>                   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ... ▶ Local vars C:\Users\internit\Dropbox\Python\codepython\codepython\home\views.py
>   in home
>       return render(request, 'home.html', {'post':post}) ... ▶ Local vars

home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from codepython.posts import views
from posts import views as ps


app_name ='home'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$/', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.userposts, name='userposts')
    url(r'^posts/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', ps.assignment_detail, name='assignment_detail'),


]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

home/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.apps import apps


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    posts = apps.get_model("posts", "Post")
    post = posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[0:6]

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'post':post})

def assignment_detail(request, post_id):
    posts = apps.get_model('posts', 'Post')
    post = get_object_or_404(posts, pk=post_id)

    return render(request, "assignment_detail.html", {'post': post})
```

home.html

```
<div class="row">
    {% for post in post.all %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">

                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Level: {{post.assignment_level}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'assignment_detail' post_id %}"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
                    <p>by {{post.author}} from {{post.pub_date}}</p>
                    <h4>{{post.assignment_body}}</h4>

                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read...</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

myproject/urls.py

```
url(r'^assignment_detail/', views.assignment_detail,name='assignment_detail'),
```

What am I missing here.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That error is Django telling you that it can't find any URLs named 'assignment_detail' that have an argument to pass in.

This is because your url entry in `myproject/urls.py` is missing the argument (`post_id`) that you use in your view. You'll need to update that url line to something similar to this:

```
url(r'^assignment_detail/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.assignment_detail, name='assignment_detail'),
```

The change at the end of the URL adds a named regular expression to capture the `post_id` value which will then be passed into the view.

Looking at your template code, you'll need to update your {% url %} block to use `post.id` (notice period) not `post_id`

Answer (score 1):

Your url does not imply that you have to pass an id, but you're passing one in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'assignment_detail' post_id %}"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
```

It should be:

```
url(r'^assignment_detail/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)', views.assignment_detail,name='assignment_detail'),
```